SVG symbols are offset (leaflet+qgis2web)
I have been looking the whole day to solve this problem that is occuring to a project made on QGIS.
The project holds SVG symbols which have pin shaped to pinpoint to the geocoded city.The problem is that on QGIS it pinpoints exactly to the city but when converted through QGIS2web with leaflet the pins are centered on the city.
Here is the link of the map where you can see the offset. I would like the bottom of the pins to pinpoint to every geocoded city (and not the center of the pins) : FDE Map
Here is a screenshot of the problem (London, Brussels and Luxemburg are not pinpointed to their exact geocode. London is in the middle of the sea.):

Here is relevant part of the code:
function style_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2_0() {
    return {
        pane: 'pane_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2',
rotationAngle: 0.0,
rotationOrigin: 'center center',
icon: L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'markers/GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2.svg',
    iconSize: [76.0, 76.0]
}),
        interactive: false,
    }
}
map.createPane('pane_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2');
map.getPane('pane_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2').style.zIndex = 402;
map.getPane('pane_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
var layer_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2 = new L.geoJson(json_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2, {
    attribution: '',
    interactive: false,
    dataVar: 'json_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2',
    layerName: 'layer_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2',
    pane: 'pane_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2',
    onEachFeature: pop_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        var context = {
            feature: feature,
            variables: {}
        };
        return L.marker(latlng, style_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2_0(feature));
    },
});
bounds_group.addLayer(layer_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2);
map.addLayer(layer_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2);

I hope I am clear.

I think I understand what you mean and I know how to solve. Can you load the qgis2web export zip somewhere and link it here?

Here is the zip extract from qgis2web : https://wildlebanon.org/FDE/qgis2web_2024_12_14-17_47_02_977411.zip

I added relevant part of the code for you.

Thanks, but where do I find this piece of code ?

This code was taken from your code at https://www.wildlebanon.org/FDE/qgis2web_2024_12_14-16_10_32_942201/. It's not a solution, it's just that coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, so I added it for you.

Display of Leaflet icon is by default centered on coordinate. Icon creation option iconAnchor can be used to offset display of icon (see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon).
I'm not familiar with qgis2web and so I don't know of there is an option to offset the icon. To do it in generated code, you would have to modify style_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2_0() function like this:
function style_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2_0() {
  return {
    pane: 'pane_GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2',
    rotationAngle: 0.0,
    rotationOrigin: 'center center',
    icon: L.icon({
      iconUrl: 'qgis2web/GeocodageNEFDERfrents_2.svg',
      iconSize: [76.0, 76.0],
      iconAnchor: [38, 76]
    }),
    interactive: false,
  }
}

This would be the result then:


Wow thanks, but I have been through all the files exported by gqis2web but couldn't locate this function.

If answer helped you solve you problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let others with similar problems know that problem was resolved.

I haven't solved yet this problem since I cannot locate this function. Where can I find the file ?

Located the file, it is in the index.html and made the modifications accordingly. Worked like a charm. Thank you very much.
